# Live Sass Compiler is Node Sass or Dart Sass?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, node-sass, dart-sass, live-sass-compiler

I found 2 extension are named Live Sass Compiler. One of them which developed by Ritwick Dey has been deprecated. And it was not compatible Dart Sass (@use or @forward). Another one is compatible.

1. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass (deprecated)
2. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass

So what kind of Sass is Live Sass Compiler using? Node Sass, Dart Sass, or not of them?

Answer (score 1):

So the **Deprecated** compiler uses **NodeSass** and the other one uses **dart-sass**(Using JavaScript API).